# Move photos to SD card on HTC Desire 310

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, insufficient-memory, photos

I have an HTC Desire 310 and my phone memory is full and can't update apps. How to move photos from my phone memory to an SD card?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much any file browser in the Play Store allows you to move files. Just download one. Find the folder. Long press on it, tell it to move. Then navigate to the folder on the SD card and off you go.